# Appending one list to another in Ansible (oneliner)

Tags: variables, ansible

I wanted to append one list to an other in Ansible. While at that, I found, that using

```
tasks:
    set_fact:
    my_list: "{{ my_list + my_append_list }}"
```

works but it requires 3 lines of code which seems to be a lot of hassle. The problem is, that using

```
my_list: "{{ my_list + my_append_list }}"
```

ends up in an infinite recursion. This type of assignment works only if a third list-name is involved (so something like `my_third_list: "{{ my_list + my_append_list }}"`)

The question is: Is there a way how to append a list to another with a single line of code and without the use of another variable making?

Thanks in advance, P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Because in Ansible in most cases you don't *assign* variables, but define templates.

Assignment:

```
- set_fact:
    my_list: "{{ my_list + my_append_list }}"
```

This is a kind of: template what is on the right side and assign the result to the left side, templating (evaluating) is done at the moment of `set_fact` execution.

Aliasing (*I invented this term, you will not find this in Ansible docs*):

```
vars:
  my_list1: "{{ my_list + my_append_list }}"
```

This is a kind of: define an alias with name `my_list1` (on the left side) for templated string on the right side. The right side will be templated (evaluated) at the moment in time, when you use `my_list1` variable in some task.

And if you use the same name on the left side and inside the expression on the right, you get infinite recursion..